# Symfony 3: Legacy People API has not been used in project , using knpu/oauth

Tags: php, symfony, oauth-2.0

Here are my project versions packages:

```
knpuniversity/oauth2-client-bundle:1.28.0
league/oauth2-google:1.0.1
symfony/symfony:3.4.12
```

I tried to build an google login, follow the official doc [OAuth / Social Integration for Symfony: KnpUOAuth2ClientBundle](https://github.com/knpuniversity/oauth2-client-bundle)

I had already activated  Legacy People API in google console.

But still getting the following error:

> Legacy People API has not been used in project  before or
> it is disabled. Enable it by visiting
> https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/legacypeople.googleapis.com/overview?project=
> then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for
> the action to propagate to our systems and retry

Comment: Just to be sure, after you activated the API you waited ~15 Minutes?

Comment: yeah, it has been enough, i don'know the max time to wait this.
Also tried to visit the link that message error gives, but getting error such: "An error occurred while loading ..."

Tnks